# How to compile html in Vue 3 without <head> tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

i'm trying to generate a html static page with Vue 3 and Vue-cli, here below vue.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
pages: {
    home: {
        // entry for the page
        entry: 'src/pages/homepage/init-page.js',
        // the source template
        template: 'public/base.html',
        // output file
        filename: 'html/home.html',
        // when using title option,
        // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
        title: 'Homepage',
        // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
        // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'home']
    }
},
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        less: {
            additionalData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.less";`
        }
    },
    extract: true
},
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('preload-home')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch-home')
    config.plugins.delete('preload-classifica')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch-classifica')
},

configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
}}
```

Here below public/base.html

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

In order to a particular structure that I have (inject this html generated file), I want to generate file without `<head>`, but actually the generated file is with `<head></head>`.

I tried to use vue-cli-plugin-html-replace but I've updated Webpack and Node locally, do you know a valid alternative or possible solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: "I tried to use vue-cli-plugin-html-replace but I've updated Webpack and Node locally" - not sure what the first part has to do with the second

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, because in the previous project with the same structure I used vue-cli-plugin-html-replace and i assumed to anticipate some answers about this